# java swing can't expand JFrame's height?

Tags: java, swing, height, layout-manager, pack

I created a JFrame and set a JPanel as its content panel, I added about 30 buttons into that container but the JFrame shows me one line of buttons and it won't allow me expand the height.

```
public class UIDemo{
    private JPanel contentPanel = new JPanel();
    private JButton buttons[] = new JButton[30];
    public UIDemo(JFrame frame){
        for(int i = 0; i < buttons.length; i++){
           buttons[i] = new JButton("Button"+Integer.toString(i));
           contentPanel.add(buttons[i]);
        }//Add all buttons into content panel.

        frame.setContentPane(contentPanel);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
    public static void main(String[] args){
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable(){
             public void run(){
                 new UIDemo(new JFrame());
             }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: The default layout of a `JPanel` is `FlowLayout`, which will show the behavior you describe.

Comment: why flowLayout can't expand the content's height?

Comment: 1st.  Try manually dragging the size of the window to other dimensions.  Make it thinner and taller.  See what happens.

Comment: Actually i can drag the size of the window taller, then i can see the bellows lines of buttons.But i wanna to the size of frame would be automatically show all lines of buttons but not only one line of buttons.

Comment: OK - my point is that `FlowLayout` will happily plonk components one beside the next as long as the parent container can get wider.  It never 'tries' to make the parent container taller, but suggests to the parent (when asked) what its preferred width and height will be.  That size will be based on a single row of components.

Comment: Also look at [`WrapLayout`](http://tips4java.wordpress.com/2008/11/06/wrap-layout/).

Comment: Yeah, this saying works. Thank u.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- `JPanel` has implemented `FlowLayout` in API
- `FlowLayout` accepting only `PreferredSize`, then `JComponents` in `JPanel` isn't resizable
- have look at `GridLayout`,
- another options are `GridBagLayout` or todays custom `MigLayout`

Comment: Actually i don't mean to resize the JComponents in JPanel.Just the size of frame wouldn't what i want. The frame just show one line of buttons, and i need to drag the frame taller manually then i can see the below line of buttons. I really can't understand the reason why the pack method can't let the frame do this litter trick.

Comment: in GridLayout (another mentioned) you'll to determine row and columns, resizable / nonresizable came from used Layout Manager, depends of your requirements

Comment: Yeah.But i'm confused about the behavior that frame size wouldn't be expanded by its content size while i use the frame.pack method. It's certain gird layout would solve this problem. But isn't it quite weird to the behavior of the flow layout just expand frame's width but not the height?

Comment: *"..isn't it quite weird to the behavior of the flow layout just expand frame's width but not the height?"* Not that weird.  If it went to set a width, what width would it set?  It might be possible if `FlowLayout` offered a `setPreferredWidth(int)` method, ..but it does not.  BTW - If you figured it out as mentioned in other comments, you could post the solution as an answer and accept it.